# С# табы и разделение кода на дополнения/модули

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим нужно написать софт, многозадачный.

К примеру, у него будет 2-5 табов с формами и кнопками.

Вопрос, визуально задачи разделить можно, а как их разделить програмно ?

Допустим сделать что-то ввиде модулей ? дополнений, над которыми можно было бы работать отдельно, а не в общем коде.

Comment: в чем проблема с `Допустим сделать что-то ввиде модулей`?

Comment: Делайте базовый класс для внутренностей таба, например `MyTabContent`, наследник от `Panel`. И дальше разные имплементации `MyTabContent` разносите по разным длл. Осталось только загрузить эти длл, создать инстансы классов и добавить их на форму.

Comment: Дело в том, что ранее такого не требовалось и в принципе хватало для мелких задач структурного програмирования, но так как постепенно задачи начали усложнятся, то решил перейти на более серьезный - правильный подход (а главное чтобы в нем потом не потерятся)

Answer (score 0):

> Вопрос, визуально задачи разделить можно, а как их разделить програмно?

Если хотите разделить, т.е. не видеть код для других табов:

- Напишите отдельные классы для каждого таба.
- Используйте свойства и методы класса в "общем коде".

Чтобы не создавать лишние классы, можно грамотно написать методы и собрать в одном классе. Т.е. вынести повторяющиеся задачи в функции, все функции не должны изменять внешние переменные и решать только 1 задачу (только читает файл и возвращает результат, а не считает его).